# How to make the hibernate map a created table?

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I have tried to model just a few columns for a already created table. But `Hibernate` can´t perform queries able to return data for the application.

I'm doing  something like this in the model that maps a created table:

```java
@Column(name="LOCALE_ID")
private String locale;

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
private Long ID;

@Column(name="TITLE")
private String title;

public Location () {}

public Long getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(Long ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getLocale() {
    return locale;
}

public void setLocale(String locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

The method that performs the query is shown below:

```java
String q = "SELECT l.title FROM " + className +
            " l WHERE l.locale = '" + locale + '"';
List<Location> result = null;
try {
    Transaction tx = getSession().beginTransaction();
    result = (List<Location>)session.createQuery(q).list();
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return result;
```

When i called this method with correct parameters, nothing is returned, but the mapped table contains data that can be fetched with those parameters.

I dont know why the hibernate can´t handle  with created tables.

Maybe an reverse engineering to generate the model, can help, but i dont know how to perform this.

Any thoughs on this?

Comment: Have you added get/set to the entity ? and @entity?

Comment: Yeah it has getters and setters

Comment: Your query is getting l.title, which is a String - any particular reason you are casting your result list to Location?

Comment: Location is the model Class

Comment: The syntax for your query is wrong, you need an extra quote at the end like WHERE l.locale = '" + locale + "'"

Comment: @Matt this was fixed, the problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

You are shadowing your List result in the try/catch block with an equally named, but new variable, to which you assign the results of the query. But you always return the outer variable assigned to null.

```
String q = "SELECT l.title FROM " + className +
            " l WHERE l.locale = '" + locale;
List<Location> result = null;
try {
    Transaction tx = getSession().beginTransaction();
    result = (List<Location>)session.createQuery(q).list();
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return result;
```

might do better

Comment: Oh sorry the code is just that I make the correction in the body question

Comment: Did you try to select the complete model class by using `String q = "SELECT l FROM " + className + " l WHERE etc.`? Otherwise you don't query your model class, but just the title as a string (as @Matt remarked).

Comment: I didn´t try something like that, maybe this that you said can work well, I´ll try

Answer (score 0):

You should use query ability to specify parameters, as probably this will be the issue.
Try something like this

```
String q = "SELECT l.name FROM yourclassname l WHERE l.locale=:locale";
List<Location> result = null;
try {
    Transaction tx = getSession().beginTransaction();
    session=yourFactory.openSession();
    query=session.createQuery(q);
    query.setParameter("locale",yourLocaleVal);
    result=query.list();
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to perform the search is with constructor expression in the SELECT, see it below:

```
String q = "Select new " + className + "(l.ID, l.title, l.locale) From " + className + " l Where l.locale = '" + locale + "'";
```